# Populate a dynamically added dropdownlist based on another dynamically added dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone help???

I want to implement in my application.

Thanks, In advance

Comment: what did you done so far? you wan't others to build your application?

Comment: You need to provide more detail in your question with specifics(with server-side postbacks, client-side AJAX, native ASP.NET or third-party libraries like jQuery or AjaxControlToolKit) or it will get closed.

Comment: I have Countries like India, USA, Africa etc. In that I added Buildings, then Floors under buildings. Now I want that if user wants to add a Room in a floor, then in dropdownlist the displayed floors should be related to the selected building.

Answer (score 2):

The `AjaxControlToolkit` has a `CascadingDropDown` control:

[CascadingDropDown Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Comment: My dropdownlist is added on runtime by the user.

Answer (score 0):

These are called cascading dropdownlists, so you can google for many examples, e.g. http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx